# How to write the select query for matched row ID?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

Hi i have a  table named EMP,which looks like this....

```
       EmpName |EmpBranchName  |ApproverId|
        Anil   |ajsdajd        |1
        Ghouse |ajkbhsdf       |1
        raghu  |asjbsdfs       |1
        sravan |ajsdf          |2
        niharika|aasfsdfs      |2
```

now when Approver with ApproverId=1 logins he has a grid in his page which sould be populated with data assigned to his id....i.e rows with column ID=AppoverID should be populated in grid..can any one tell me how to write query for this......i can take care of populating to grid...

Thank you...

Comment: didn't understand your question....please elaborate it...
but what i get i this... select * from EMP where approverId='1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely it's just...

```
select EmpName, EmpBranchName  
from Emp  
where ApproverId = @ApproverId
```

You just need to identify `@ApproverId` from whoever logs in and pass that into the query

Answer (score 1):

or could be something like

```
Select 
    Positions.JobTitle,
   Positions.StaffMember,
   Positions.ApproverId,
   emp.EmpName,
   emp.ApproverId

from   Positions 
inner join emp on positions.ApproverId = emp.ApproverId
```

this will only show Posts to which only ApproverID's (be it 1 2 or 3) can see